# python + converting time zone, astimezone() not returning expected value

Tags: python

I have the current DateTime64 object (from pandas). It's currently in GMT.   Its string form is:

> time = 2017-01-02 23:00:00

I then try to convert it from GMT to EST.

```
dt = timezone('GMT').localize(time)
time = dt.astimezone(timezone('US/Eastern'))
```

When I run this, this returns (in string form)

> 2017-01-02 23:00:00+00:00

Ie, its not converting it from GMT to EST.  Any idea why?

Comment: It would be great if you could show us where you imported ```timezone``` from and what type ```time``` is. Using ```pytz.timezone``` with ```time``` being a naive ```datetime.datetime``` (converted by ```datetime64_variable.astype(datetime)```) instance it works fine for me.

Comment: you know what - I dont think this is an error in the above. The part I don't have, is I add the time into a series, and append to a dataframe. Its the dataframe append thats converting it back to UST i think!

Answer (score 2):

You may use `pytz` to transfer the timezone as following:

```
import pytz
import datetime

gmt = pytz.timezone('GMT')
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
time = "2017-01-02 23:00:00"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(date)
dategmt = gmt.localize(date)
print(dategmt)
dateeastern = dategmt.astimezone(eastern)
print(dateeastern)
```

First you have to read the time as local time and `localize` it, then use `astimezone` to make it as eastern time. Hope this can help.